# Htaccess not working with?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a list of URLs, but any of them that have a ? it isn't working. For example, here's my line of code...

```
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/day/date/2013-03-28/227.html?print=1&tmpl=component https://example.com/index.php/calendar/
```

This doesn't redirect. However, if I use this...

```
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/day/date/2013-03-28/227.html https://example.com/index.php/calendar/
```

...or this...

```
Redirect 301 /calendar-of-events/day/date/2013-03-28/227.html&tmpl=component https://example.com/index.php/calendar/
```

...and test the URLs out, they redirect correctly.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^print=1&tmpl=component$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^calendar-of-events/day/date/2013-03-28/227\.html$ https://example.com/index.php/calendar/? [L,R=301]
```